# Print result of query in a table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an index method in a controller that returns a collection(https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) to a view

```
public function index()
{
    $categoriePdf = new CategorieDocumenti;
    $categoriePdf = DB::table('categorie_documenti')
    ->select('id','descrizione','per_veicolo')
    ->get();
    return view('elenca_categoria_pdf', ['campi' => $categoriePdf]);
}
```

In the view I want to print the result of the query in an adminlte table.

I got the tamplate from here https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki
and the table i want to setup is this https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Tool-Components#datatables

[Here is the screenshot of how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXKXK.png)

I want the same thing but not with static data as the example does but with the content of the collection

I tried for hours but I cant understand how to put all the rows of the collection in $config['data'] array as the example does with static data:

```
$config = [
'data' => [
    [22, 'John Bender', '+02 (123) 123456789', '<nobr>'.$btnEdit.$btnDelete.$btnDetails.'</nobr>'],
    [19, 'Sophia Clemens', '+99 (987) 987654321', '<nobr>'.$btnEdit.$btnDelete.$btnDetails.'</nobr>'],
    [3, 'Peter Sousa', '+69 (555) 12367345243', '<nobr>'.$btnEdit.$btnDelete.$btnDetails.'</nobr>'],
],
```

Comment: so, do you want to use the result as an array?

Comment: like `$config['data'][0]` ?

Comment: @MiteshRathod i would like to cycle on the collection like you can do with foreach

Comment: @foreach($data as $datas)<tr><td>{{$datas->id}}</td></tr>@endforeach

Do you want something like this??

Comment: It will loop all through you table and display the result in a table

Comment: @eraufi I did as you suggested and it works perfectly; I was led astray by the 'data' array when it wasnt necessary; I put a <td> per column

Comment: and what was the result? was it what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your controller to

```
public function index()
{
    $categoriePdf = new CategorieDocumenti;
    $categoriePdf = DB::table('categorie_documenti')
    ->select('id','descrizione','per_veicolo')
    ->get();
    return view('elenca_categoria_pdf',compact('categoriePdf'));
}
```

then in your view blade file do something like this

```
 <thead>
 <th>{{ __('id') }}</th>
<th>{{ __('Name') }}</th>
<th>{{ __('Actions') }}</th>
</thead>
<body>
@foreach($categoriePdf as $categoriePdfs)
<tr>
<td>{{$categoriePdfs->id}}</td>
<td>{{$categoriePdfs->name}}</td>
<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="add"/></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
 </tbody>
 </table>
```